# Inserting value into password field with a script in JS through a WebEngine in JavaFX

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, webengine

I aim for automatically logging into `Google Calendar` through a `WebEngine` in `JavaFX` and show it in a `WebView`. But I can't seem to insert a string value into the password field even though it works perfectly with the username field.

I have tried creating the script in Java with `Element e = webEngine.getDocument().getElementById(password)` and inserting the value with `e.setAttribute("value","mypassword")`, but this doesn't work either. It provides no stack traces meaning that the element exists, but I can't insert the value somehow.

```
    System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
    WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
    webEngine.load("https://calendar.google.com");
    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
         new ChangeListener<State>() {
               @Override
               public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
               if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                      webEngine.executeScript(
                            "function login(user){"
                          + " var usernameField = document.getElementById(\"identifierId\");"
                          + " usernameField.value = user;"
                          + " var sButton = document.getElementById(\"identifierNext\");"
                          + " sButton.click();"
                          + "}"
                          + "login('myusername');"
                       );
                }
        }
    });
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Platform.runLater( () -> {
                webEngine.executeScript(
                    "function login(pass){"
                            + " var passwordField = document.getElementById(\"password\");"
                            + " passwordField.value = pass;"
                            + " var sButton = document.getElementById(\"passwordNext\");"
                            + " sButton.click();"
                            + "}"
                            + "login('mypassword');"
             );
         });
    });
    t.start();
```

The result should be, that the listener waits for the page to load and then fill the username and click next. Then the thread begins but waits 5 seconds to make sure that next has been clicked and then it should fill in the password credentials but doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Using `"document.querySelector(\"#password > div.aCsJod.oJeWuf > div > div.Xb9hP > input\");"` instead of `document.getElementById(\"password\");` finds the password field.